# Start ruby debugger if rspec test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-debug, pry

Often, when a test fails, I spend quite sometime trying to figure out the what caused it to fail. It'd be useful if RSpec could kick off a Ruby debugger when the test fails, so that I can inspect the local variables immediately to drill down on the cause.

The work-around I'm using right now looks something like this:

```
# withing some test
debugger unless some_variable.nil?
expect(some_variable).to be_nil
```

However, this approach is cumbersome, because I first wait for a test to fail, then add the debugger line, fix the issue and then have to remove the debugger line, whereas I want it work more like `gdb` which has the ability to kick in when an exception is hit, without requiring to pepper your code base with `debugger` statements.

Edit: I've tried Plymouth. It hasn't worked reliably enough for me. Also the development history seems to indicate that it isn't a very well supported gem, so I'd rather not rely on it.

**Update**: I tried out `pry-rescue` and find it to be neat. However, I use [zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) a lot and was wondering if there's a way to make it work with `pry-rescue`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [pry-rescue](https://github.com/conradirwin/pry-rescue), it's the spiritual successor to plymouth:

From the Readme:

If you're using RSpec or respec, you can open a pry session on every test failure using rescue rspec or rescue respec:

```
$ rescue rspec
From: /home/conrad/0/ruby/pry-rescue/examples/example_spec.rb @ line 9 :

     6:
     7: describe "Float" do
     8:   it "should be able to add" do
 =>  9:     (0.1 + 0.2).should == 0.3
    10:   end
    11: end

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected: 0.3
     got: 0.30000000000000004 (using ==)
[1] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Just tried it with the newest zeus and pry-rescue version, doesn't work

Comment: I'm able to get control upon test case failure but I don't have access to associations, example `customer.addresses` returns a `[]` while there are addresses.

Answer (score 11):

You won't get access to local variables (easily) without `debugger` being in scope of the block, however `RSpec` provides you with around hooks which let's you do this:

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
  result = example.run
  debugger if result.is_a?(Exception)
  puts "Debugging enabled"
end
```

You then have access to `@ivars` and `subject` / `let(:var)` contents at this point.

Comment: Interesting. This would not catch test failures though, would it?

Answer (score 11):

I like @jon-rowe's solution (no additional gems needed) with a slight edit: I really don't care about other errors as much as `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError`.

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
  example.run.tap do |result|
    debugger if result.is_a?(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

From the Rspec documentation:

> RSpec tries to provide useful failure messages, but for cases in which you want more specific information, you can define your own message right in the example.This works for any matcher other than the operator matchers.

What I do is to invoke pry in that message. See the example:

```
describe "failing" do
  context "test" do
    it "should start pry" do
      a = 3
      b = 1
      expect(a).to be == b, "#{require 'pry';binding.pry}"
    end
  end
end
```

Happy debugging!

Comment: If you're not using a repl, or don't have one available, this alternative message is the perfect place to (temporarily) drop an `inspect` or some other bit of debugging information.

Comment: Slick Rick! Note, if you're already requiring `pry`, I was able to use just `expect(a).to be == b, binding.pry`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the ExpectationNotMatched exception while it's being constructed. Include the following code in your helpers somewhere and RSpec will stop when the exception is being constructed. This will be several levels deep inside the matchers, so in the debugger, say "where" then "up 5"or "up 6" and you'll be inside the instance_exec of your block. The debugger doesn't show the code correctly in the version I'm using, but you can "up" one more time and get to code running in the same context where your test is evaluated, so you can inspect the instance variables (but not local variables, it seems).

```
require 'debugger'
require 'rspec'

Debugger.start
class RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
  alias_method :firstaid_initialize, :initialize

  def initialize *args, &b
    send(:firstaid_initialize, *args, &b)
    puts "Stopped due to #{self.class}: #{message} at "+caller*"\n\t"
    debugger
    true # Exception thrown
  end
end

describe "RSpec" do
  it "should load use exceptions on should failure" do
    @foo = :bar    # An instance variable I can examine
    1.should == 2
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll try it out. Thanks, Clifford!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **plymouth** gem https://github.com/banister/plymouth for that. It is using **pry** though, a (better) alternative to **irb**.

HTH

Comment: I've tried Plymouth. It hasn't worked reliably enough for me. Also the development history seems to indicate that it isn't a very well supported gem, so I'd rather not rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [hammertime](https://github.com/avdi/hammertime). It will stop and prompt to take you into an interactive debugging session whenever an exception is raised.

Comment: [pry-rescue](https://github.com/conradirwin/pry-rescue) (a pry plugin) is far superior to hammertime, it drops you in the actual context of the exception and lets you walk the stack